# z-index with overflow and popup inside it

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I have a popup that appears when clicking on a text element, the problem is that this text is inside a container with overflow because it is a document. My problem is that when I click to make the popup appear, this popup is inside the container but it doesn't display well, and I've already tried the z-index in several ways and it doesn't work. The popup should be displayed completely and as if it were outside the container. The popup is generated by a specific library (ckeditor) and I don't have access to the code directly or to modify it.

[image]

Comment: See if a solution similar to https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ can help.

Comment: It'll be because your parent container creates a new stacking context for your popup. Because you've set the overflow attribute in that container to scroll, rather than overflowing and appearing to float above it, the scrollbars appear in and it's clipped. Have a look about stacking contexts here https://tiffanybbrown.com/2015/09/css-stacking-contexts-wtf/

Comment: the scroll width can be calculated. In general if you consider it's 16px width, you'll cover 99% of the cases without being obliged to calculate. If you have  a "main" in your body and everything else in the main, put a margin-right 16px

Comment: Hello , you should write some part of codes so I can help you, a picture does not help to understand the hole issue. But through the picture I see that your popup's body's container is made with a CSS overflow rule, that way you should to share your code so we can solve it by an alternative solution.